# Cannot change permission of external ExFAT HDD folders

Tags: macos, external-disk, permission, folders, exfat

I can't change permissions of external HDD folders The file system is ExFAT and I am on OSX. Here is what is shown when I do `ls`:

```
drwxrwxrwx@
```

I don't even understand what `@` means at the end. Is it the reason why I can't `chmod` permissions?

Comment: Please post the output of `mount` relative to your external HD.

Comment: ExFAT has no support for ownership or permissions as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

The @ at the end of the name means that the Finder has extended attributes OTHER than an ACL but might also be all manner of other things (Finder info for one). You can see what attributes are by `ls -le@`.